# Is there a way to create a function using unexported type as parameter in Golang?

Tags: go

In my application, I have a struct for which I defined a `New` function to create instances as zero values of the fields are not meaningful. In addition, I didn't export the struct. So the only way to create is via `New`.

```
var goodPerson = person.New("James", "Tran")

goodPerson.PrintFullName()
```

On the caller side, I have no idea how to create a function that takes in the unexported type as a parameter in such a way that I can still access the exported methods of this type.

```
func doBadThingToGoodPeople(goodPerson <???>) {
   goodPerson.PrintFullName()
}
```

I'd be very grateful if you could point me in a direction.

Comment: You can't name an unexported type in another package. You have to refactor _something_ -- export the name, move the function to the same package, use an interface, etc.

Comment: Just make the type exported. If there is a "New" function to produce it, anyone with some basic familiarity with Go APIs (like the standard library), would probably know that you shouldn't use an uninitialized value, as it's a common convention. Also make `New` return a pointer type if you want discouragement against creating variables/fields of the direct struct type (which will be uninitialized).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an interface:

```
type FullNameSupport interface {
  PrintFullName()
}

func doBadThingToGoodPeople(goodPerson FullNameSupport) {
   goodPerson.PrintFullName()
}
```

This way don't have to export the type.